# RelativePanel arrangement in UserControl crashes the parent page's Visual Studio designer in my UWP app

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

When I try to use a `RelativePanel` container within a `UserControl`, which is then subsequently used in another/parent page within a `DataTemplate`  for a `GridView` or `ListView` it crashes the Visual Studio designer for that page. At run-time, it still works, but without being able to see the result within the Visual Studio designer, I am having to go back to using `StackPanel` controls instead, which works.

Note that I am using x:Bind within my `UserConrol` and that the crash in the Visual Studio designer only happens when I try to arrange the child controls with the `RelativePanel` using something like the `RelativePanel.Below` property.

The exception thrown in the designer is like:

[image]

I am using xRelatedMovieImg in the UserControl as follows:

```
RelativePanel.Below="xRelatedMovieImg"
```

So has anyone else seen this issue and if so he is there a fix or work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was experiencing the same issue. Found that using `Binding` worked in my case. So yours might be
`RelativePanel.Below="{Binding ElementName=xRelatedMovieImg}"`

Comment: Note that this is still an issue when using x:Bind, but as no other solutions have been given for a while then I will mark that using standard runtime Binding in a user control will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've experienced, the Designer can be very fragile and crash for the weirdest things. Usually it helps by doing a rebuild of the project (Ctrl+Shift+B).

Also, if you're only changing the design and not debugging you can get faster launches by using "Start without debugging" (Ctrl+F5) from the Debug menu in Visual Studio. That way you don't have to wait for the debugger to get everything set up.

Comment: So rebuilding the project makes no difference in this case. I have even tried using x86 build config instead of x64 and when in x86, I tried to even disable the project code button in the designer, but it made no difference to the exception thrown in the designer.